# Can we use column name in mysql in clause?

Tags: mysql, clause, inner-query

```
SELECT `e`.`id`, `e`.`title`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`event_time`,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( name SEPARATOR " | " ) 
FROM `ar_products` 
WHERE id IN **(e.products)** AS products FROM events e;
```

I have list of comma separated product id's in events table with column name products. If I use the values 54,33,23.. it is showing correct values like list of products `[product1 | product2 | ..]`.

Its not working when I use column name directly in IN CLAUSE.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Answer (score 20):

It sound like you are looking for `FIND_IN_SET` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set. Change the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, e.products) AS products FROM events e;
```